# How to close modal after submit in angular?

Tags: jquery, angular, modal-dialog

I have this modal form to submit. After searching in stackoverflow, found code in jQuery to close it but is not working for me! This jquery code is in **index.html**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".modal :button").click(function(){
        $('.modal').modal('hide');
    });
  });
```

Its like is not binding to those .modal and submit button at all.
Also tried to bind click event from id of button but not working again

Comment: are you using a component library or you created a modal from scratch? FYI it's not good practice to use jQuery in Angular or any other JS framework

Comment: I'm using bootstrap cdn, so I have no other choice

Comment: There's ngbootstrap which has no dependency on jQuery

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap as your code indicates - then simply add the data-dismiss="modal" attribute to the buttons in the modal and it will close the modal on  the click.

eg :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right"  data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src=" https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#demo-modal" class="btn btn-default">Click to show modal</button>


<div id="demo-modal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
     </button>
          <h4>Modal header</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body clearfix">
         <p>Modal body</p>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right"  data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
     </div>
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: dismiss-modal close modal before data is submit